# Timeout setting for SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I am using VSTS 2008 + ADO.Net + C# + .Net 3.5 + SQL Server 2008. I am using ADO.Net at client side to connect to database server to execute a store procedure, then return result from the store procedure.

Here is my code. I have two issues about timeout,

1. If I do not explicitly set any timeout related settings, for the connection to database server, are there any timeout settings (e.g. if can not connect to database server for some default amount of time, there will be some timeout exception?)?
2. If I do not explicitly set any timeout related settings, for the execution of the store procedure, are there any timeout settings (e.g. if can not retrieve results from server to ADO.Net client for some default amount of time, there will be some timeout exception?)?

   ```
       using (SqlConnection currentConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=true;Asynchronous Processing=true"))
       {
           // check current batch conut
           currentConnection.Open();
           using (SqlCommand RetrieveOrderCommand = new SqlCommand())
           {
               RetrieveOrderCommand.Connection = currentConnection;
               RetrieveOrderCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               RetrieveOrderCommand.CommandText = "prc_GetOrders";
               RetrieveBatchCountCommand.Parameters.Add("@Count", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
               RetrieveBatchCountCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
               int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(RetrieveOrderCommand.Parameters["@Count"].Value);
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 52):

As gbn already mentioned, there are two types of timeouts:

1) Connection Timeout: this is controlled by your connection string:

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDB;
   Trusted_Connection=true;Asynchronous Processing=true
```

If you add a  `Connect Timeout=120`  to this string, your connection will try for 120 seconds to get opened and then aborts.

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestDB;
   Trusted_Connection=true;Asynchronous Processing=true;
   Connect Timeout=120;
```

2) Command timeout: for each command, you can also specify a timeout - ADO.NET will wait for that amount of time before cancelling out your query. You specify that on the SqlCommand object:

```
    using (SqlCommand RetrieveOrderCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
       RetrieveOrderCommand.CommandTimeout = 150;
    }
```

Comment: It might also be noteworthy to include that the 'Connect Timeout' parameter on the connection string also controls the time-out for the SqlTransaction.Commit method

Comment: Thanks Marc, what kinds of exception will be thrown or in other words what kinds of exception we should catch in our code to handle timeout issue?

Comment: Thanks Philip, do you mean besides connection timeout and command timeout, there is a 3rd type of timeout called Transaction timeout?

Comment: @George2, yes that is correct. It an obscure one that caught us in production. Here is some information on it.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/d9a98276-e201-4f38-abda-e4044df668c1/

Comment: Thanks for command time out, commit timeout and connection timeout, what kinds of exception should we catch?

Comment: For connection, you would typically see SqlException (if something in general does wrong), SecurityException (if permissions are missing in a partial-trust environment), or an ArgumentException, if the connection string is invalid. The SqlCommand has the SqlException as the general exception, plus InvalidArgument or SecurityEXceptions as well, depending on the methods you call - see the MSDN docs for details which exception is thrown by which methods (too many to list here)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx has some useful example code for triggering a command timeout exception.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there are 2 kinds of timeout that can be set

1. [Connection timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)
2. [Command timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(VS.80).aspx)

Both default to 30 seconds in VBA, .net etc

Comment: Thanks gbn! What kinds of exception will be thrown or in other words what kinds of exception we should catch in our code to handle timeout issue?

Comment: In SSMS, I get "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." YOu can test using WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:40' to force a 40 second wait and exception for Command timeout. For connection timeout, you can make up a server name and try to connect.

Comment: Thanks, for command timeout, what kinds of exception should be caught?

Answer (score 0):

In `sqlconnection` class, there is a property by name `ConnectionTimeout`.

This cannot be directly used to set desired connection timeout value as it is readonly i.e. only "get" is implemented & "set" is not implemented on this property.So we have to use keyword "Connection Timeout" in the connection string itself & set the desired value.

exi:

`Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30";(30 means 30 seconds)`

30 seconds is the maximum time given to establish connection to the server(like `172.160.0.2` OR something like `ADMINISTRATOR\\SQLEXPRESS`).If it could not immediately establish connection to server , then it will try up to 30 seconds.

If server is valid & is able to connect to server & if database name or login credentials are invalid , then this timeout won't be applicable.It immediately throws exception for invalid credentials or database