# Forcing a specific stored procedure to stop after 30 seconds: I do not want to reconfigure the timeout of the whole DB

Tags: sql-server

(The reason *why* I need the following are unimportant)

What I'd like to do is adjust the following so that it executes the stored procedure, which usually takes 30 minutes, but then the procedure stops after a set time of 60 seconds - effectively the same as if I am in `SSMS` running the procedure and press the cancel button after 60 seconds.

I don't want to reconfigure the whole db so that every other long running stored procedure times out after 30 seconds - only the specific procedure `TESTexecuteLongRunningProc`.

Here is the test procedure being called:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TESTlongRunningProc] 
AS
BEGIN

   --placeholder that represents the long-running proc
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00';

END;
```

This is the proc I would like to adjust so it cancels itself after 60 seconds:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TESTexecuteLongRunningProc] 
AS
BEGIN

    EXECUTE WH.dbo.TESTlongRunningProc;

    -->>here I would like some code that cancels TESTexecuteLongRunningProc after 60 seconds

END;
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1354333/673707

Comment: @Helio Thanks. I need to do this inside the tsql procedure - is the syntax in the link you sent me? (I don't see it)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189040.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set timeout for a stored procedure in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005254/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

Comment: @RubensFarias I only want to stop the stored procedure `TESTexecuteLongRunningProc` - any other procedure on our db can run for hours if they like. So a little unsure how your link helps?

Comment: @whytheq maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360016/setting-query-timeout-on-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2005 . But still a dupe

Comment: @whytheq first, what are you trying to prevent? Maybe there's an alternative solution.

Comment: @jomsk1e it is unimportant: I'm just interested to know if it is at all possible. Currently it seems like I will need to write a small .NET console application to run this script - then the timeout option will be possible.

Comment: "The reason why I need the following are unimportant"  is never unimportant.  Sometimes the best solution is an alternative to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Gene - it is a can of worms as far as this question is concerned (includes OPENQUERY, MDX, night batch and cube refreshing, linked servers) - trust me it is better to say "The reason why I need the following are unimportant"  !!

Comment: Can you build a second worker process to track the specific thread? and then kill it after its reach a certain overall time.  there are plenty of DMV's that can get you the info you need.  This can all be done in T-SQL

Comment: @BradD sounds good - are you able to implement this idea within an answer?

Comment: @whytheq - yes, I'll post it up in a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you can create a separate process to watch the background for a specific tasks and metrics and kill if necessary.  Lets start by implanting a tracking device into your code you wish to track.  I used a comment block with a key phrase "Kill Me".  You can place something similar in your original code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TrackedToKill
-- EXEC TrackedToKill
/* Comment Block tracking device: Kill Me*/
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Counter bigint = 0
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
END
END
```

Then lets see if we can find the running sessions

```
SELECT session_id,
command,database_id,user_id,
wait_type,wait_resource,wait_time,
percent_complete,estimated_completion_time,
total_elapsed_time,reads,writes,text
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sys.dm_exec_requests.sql_handle)
WHERE text LIKE '%Kill Me%'
AND session_id <> @@SPID
```

OK Great, this should return sessions with your tracking device.  We can then turn this into another stored procedure that will kill your processes based on the tracking device and any other criteria you might need.  You can launch this manually or perhaps with the SQL agent at start up.  Include as many additional criteria you need to make sure you limit the scope of what you're killing (ie; User, database, block or Processes that that haven't been rolled back already).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HunterKiller
-- EXEC  HunterKiller
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SessionToKill int
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(3000)
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
SET @SessionToKill = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sys.dm_exec_requests.sql_handle)
    WHERE session_id <> @@SPID 
    AND text LIKE '%Kill Me%'
    AND total_elapsed_time >= 15000)
SET @SQL = 'KILL ' + CONVERT(nvarchar,@SessionToKill)
EXEC (@SQL)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use the SQL Server Agent, perhaps using the sp_start_job and sp_stop_job procedures could work for you.

This is untested and without any sort of warranty, and the parameters have been shortened for readability:

```
-- control procedure


declare @starttime DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()

exec msdb..sp_start_job 'Job' -- The job containing the target procedure that takes 30 minutes

while 1>0

    BEGIN
        -- Check to see if the job is still running and if it has been running long enough
        IF EXISTS(
                        SELECT TOP 1 b.NAME
                        FROM msdb..sysjobactivity a
                        INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobs b
                               ON a.job_id = b.job_id
                        WHERE start_execution_date >= @starttime
                               AND stop_execution_date IS NULL
                               AND b.NAME in ('job')
                               and DATEDIFF(second,start_execution_date,SYSDATETIME()) >= 60
                  ) 
        BEGIN

            exec msdb..sp_stop_job 'Job'

        END

    waitfor delay '00:00:05';

END
```