# How to Increasing the Command Timeout in CodingHorror("my sql query").Execute();

Tags: subsonic

I am trying to create a database backup and using CodingHorror to execute my command as below. 
*CodingHorror("my sql query").Execute();*

My database size is big and it takes about 2 minutes to complete the backup process when I executed my command in MSSQL. But while executing in my C# application, exception is thrown as below
*Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.*

Is there any way to increase command timeout in Subsonic CodingHorror ?

Answer (score 0):

CodingHorror uses the normal DataProvider so it should just use the timeout you've set in the connection string q.v. [Timeout setting for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354271/timeout-setting-for-sql-server)

Comment: Added Connection Timeout in connection string of web.config still throws same exception